# How to ignore uppercase/lowercase when selecting pathname? JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if (pathname == "/" || pathname == "/default.asp")
```

*in js using jquery library.*

I want this to catch "Default.asp" as well as "DeFaULT.asp" and "default.asp"

halp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`string.toLowerCase()` method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp), this is base javascript, no jQuery needed:

```
pathname = pathname.toLowerCase();
if (pathname == "/" || pathname == "/default.asp") {
  //case in-sensitive math!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this might work:

if (pathname == "/" || pathname.toLowerCase() == "/default.asp")